# How to set the path on an S3 origin using CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, aws-cloudformation

I know that it is possible to set the path manually for a *CloudFront* distribution to point to a subfolder of an *S3* bucket.

How do I set the path property using the *CloudFormation* *JSON* configuration?

```
"CloudFrontDistribution" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::CloudFront::Distribution",
    "Properties" : {
        "DistributionConfig" : {
            "Origins" : [ {
                "DomainName": { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "DataBucket", "DomainName" ] },
                "Id" : "S3Origin",
                "S3OriginConfig" : {}
            }],
            ...
```

I've checked the *CloudFormation* docs about *CloudFront* distributions[[1]](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-origin.html#cfn-cloudfront-origin-s3origin), but they don't mention anything about a path property.

Answer (score 0):

I see that path as origin was released (relatively) recently, last December - see this forum post: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=2806.
Probably CloudFormation didn't pick up this update. Might be worth contacting their support to see when this will be available.